# Python permission denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to run 'pip install notebook --upgrade' but I am getting this error. I have tried running as administrator but that does not fix the problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3252, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3235, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3264, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 574, in _build_master
    ws = cls()
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 567, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 623, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2065, in find_on_path
    for dist in factory(fullpath):
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2127, in distributions_from_metadata
    if len(os.listdir(path)) == 0:
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\administrator\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\~etuptools-49.2.1.dist-info'
```

Comment: try `pip install --user notebook --upgrade`

Comment: yes I tried this @rafadeboas but it still gives the same error

Comment: and have you tried `python3.9 -m pip install --user notebook --upgrade`?

Comment: @rafadeboas just tried. It says python 3.9 is not recognized as internal or external command

Comment: try `python39` instead (i'm not sure how python was installed in your system)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the cmd as admin. Then, try upgrading the modules. This could also happen when the installation was not done correctly or the module requires a certain version which could occur in 3.9 since it's new.

Comment: Yes I tried running as admin but that didn't work out, It gives the same errors.

Comment: (Forgot to add) I recommend not updating to 3.9 yet because some modules are still used to 3.7 or 3.8. So, 3.9 could be the issue here.

Comment: Should I delete this python version and install 3.7 or 3.8?

Comment: @OsamaYounus I recommend 3.8, Before you downgrade, Make sure you've tried reinstalling the module.